# Dash client-side JS not executing on page return

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app where I added a JS code to print.window on button. The code works fine on each page of the multipage app and when printing multiple times on the page, but once I migrate back to a page I previously hit the button, it fails to work. Would this be a JS not executing problem? or something else? The code should execute 'on click', not on n_clicks count so nothing needs to be reset to zero. Thanks.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


index_page = html.Div([
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
])

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 1'),
    html.Div(id='hidden-content'),
    dbc.Button('Print', id='printing', color="#D3D3D3", outline=False, style={"background": "transparent",
                                                                              'color': 'grey',
                                                                              'border': '0px'},
               className="mr-1"),
    html.Div(id='page-1-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/'),
])

@callback(Output('page-1-content', 'children'),
              [Input('page-1-dropdown', 'value')])
def page_1_dropdown(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'


page_2_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 2'),
    dbc.Button('Print', id='printing', color="#D3D3D3", outline=False, style={"background": "transparent",
                                                                              'color': 'grey',
                                                                              'border': '0px'},
               className="mr-1"),
    html.Div(id='page-2-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/')
])

@callback(Output('page-2-content', 'children'),
              [Input('page-2-radios', 'value')])
def page_2_radios(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'


# Update the index
@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/page-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/page-2':
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return index_page
    # You could also return a 404 "URL not found" page here


app.clientside_callback(
    """
(function() {
    registerPrintButtonHandler();
    return;

    function registerPrintButtonHandler() {
        var button = document.getElementById("printing");

        if (!button || button.onclick === onPrintButtonClick) {
            setTimeout(registerPrintButtonHandler, 500);
            return;
        }

        button.onclick = onPrintButtonClick;
    }

    function onPrintButtonClick() {
    {
    setTimeout(window.print, 700);
};
    }
})();
    """,
    Output('blank-output2', 'children'),
    Input('printing', 'value')
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you add a complete (i.e. runnable) MWE? That would ease reproduction/debugging of the issue.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on why you are not using Dash callback rather than doing JS event handling manually?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a copy and paste functional MWE that seems to replicate my issue. Specifically, when I navigate from "home page" to page 1 and hit print, it works well, but when I nagivate "home" and back to page one I cannot get it to execute.

Comment: As per your question: I believe print.window() functions cannot be executed with a Dash callback but necessitate either a client-side callback or JS file in the  assetsf folder. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just tested your code, and on my PC, the print popup is shown on every button click.

Comment: I tried the code again in Safari and Chrome. Both replicated the failure. To clarify, the problem occurs going to page 1 -> back  to home page  and -> returning to page 1. The print function fails to execute. However, if I  navigate from page 1-2 and back to  page 1 it works fine.  Quite bizarre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is caused by the complex, custom event registration you are performing in the JavaScript layer. In Dash, it is generally recommended to attach callbacks directly to relevant properties instead. For your case, a such callback could be,

```
app.clientside_callback("""function(n_clicks){
    if(n_clicks){setTimeout(window.print, 700)};
}""", Output("dummy", "children"), Input("printing", "n_clicks"))
```

where the output is a dummy element that I added to the layout,

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
    html.Div(id='dummy')
])
```

For completeness, here is the full code,

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
    html.Div(id='dummy')
])

index_page = html.Div([
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
])

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 1'),
    html.Div(id='hidden-content'),
    dbc.Button('Print', id='printing'),
    html.Div(id='page-1-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/'),
])


@callback(Output('page-1-content', 'children'),
          [Input('page-1-dropdown', 'value')])
def page_1_dropdown(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'


page_2_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 2'),
    dbc.Button('Print', id='printing'),
    html.Div(id='page-2-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/')
])


@callback(Output('page-2-content', 'children'),
          [Input('page-2-radios', 'value')])
def page_2_radios(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'


# Update the index
@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
          [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/page-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/page-2':
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return index_page
    # You could also return a 404 "URL not found" page here


app.clientside_callback("""function(n_clicks){
    if(n_clicks){setTimeout(window.print, 700)};
}""", Output("dummy", "children"), Input("printing", "n_clicks"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```